# Am sending an entry in which there is timeA and timeB and want that if that time is already in the table my entry should not be inserted

Tags: php

Am sending an adjustment in table in which there are 2 time
Time A and Time B they both are stored as varchar in table
I want that if the adjustment is already in the table between that time so user can not enter any other entry
Please help am new in mysqli and php

```
$required_request = mysql_query("select * from swaps_prac_wfm where csrid = '$_SESSION[userid]' and (start_time<='$a' or start_time>='$b') ");
$rows_require = mysqli_num_rows($required_request); 
if (!$rows_require){ 
    insert
} 
else { 
    you already have adjustment between that time.
}
```

Comment: Any code you have so far?

Comment: `$required_request = mysql_query("select * from swaps_prac_wfm where csrid = '$_SESSION[userid]' and (start_time<='$a' or start_time>='$b') ");     
$rows_require = mysqli_num_rows($required_request);
if (!$rows_require){
insert
}
else{
you already have adjustment between that time.
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `VARCHAR` columns to `date/datetime` type because compareing `VARCHARs` whould return incorrect result.

You say you need to check if there is an entry between `TimeA` and `TimeB` then you should replace `OR` in your query with `AND`

The rest of your code is OK. I just added little corrections:

```
$required_request = mysql_query("select * from swaps_prac_wfm where csrid = '$_SESSION[userid]' and (start_time<='$a' AND start_time>='$b') ");
$rows_require = mysqli_num_rows($required_request);
if ((int) $rows_require === 0)
{
    insert
} else{
    you already have adjustment between that time.
}
```